# How to get this output inside loop?

Tags: php

This is my code

```
<?php
$target = "http://www.example.com/";
$p="&p=";
$page=5;
for($yy=2; $yy<=$page; $yy++){
        $link=$target.$p.$yy;
            echo $link."\r\n";
}
?>
```

Output

```
http://www.example.com/&p=2 
http://www.example.com/&p=3 
http://www.example.com/&p=4 
http://www.example.com/&p=5
```

I am a biginner in php ,I don't know how to get this output inside loop?

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/&p=2 
http://www.example.com/&p=3 
http://www.example.com/&p=4 
http://www.example.com/&p=5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<?php
$target = "http://www.example.com/";
$p="&p=";
$page=5;

for($yy=1; $yy<=$page; $yy++){
   if ($yy == 1) $link = $target;
   else $link = $target.$p.$yy;

   echo $link."\r\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$target = "http://www.example.com/";
$p="&p=";
$page=5;
for($yy=1; $yy<=$page; $yy++) {
    ($yy==1)?$link=$target:$link=$target.$p.$yy;
    echo $link."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `range()` and `foreach()` together instead `for`, you can make this as dynamic as you want

```
$target = 'http://www.example.com/';

$page = 5;

foreach(range(1,$page) as $i)
{
    if($i==1) $link = $target;
    else $link = $target."?p=$i";
    echo $link."<br>";
}
```

will output

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/&p=2 
http://www.example.com/&p=3 
http://www.example.com/&p=4 
http://www.example.com/&p=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Irvin Lim's answer is totally correct. It can also be written as follows:

```
<?php
$target = "http://www.example.com/";
$p="&p=";
$page=5;

for($yy=1; $yy<=$page; $yy++){
    if ($yy == 1) { 
        $link = $target;
    }
    else {
        $link = $target.$p.$yy;
    }
   echo $link."\r\n";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you wanna do with the result, but to just get the output you can do this too

```
<?php
$target = "http://www.example.com/";
$p = "&p=";
$page = 5;

for ($yy=2; $yy<=$page; $yy++) {
   if (2 === $yy) {
      echo $target."\r\n";
   }

   echo $target.$p.$yy."\r\n";
}
?>
```